# Hibernate hbm2ddl to create a table, without recreating a related table

Tags: hibernate

I am using Hibernate. I have two tables related with a many-to-many mapping. The tables are Course and Student. Course defines a many-to-many relationship to Student.

```
@Entity
public class Course {

    @ManyToMany
    public List<StudentData> getStudents() {
        return students;
    }

    public void setStudents(List<StudentData> students) {
        this.students = students;
    }

}
```

If I set the hbm2ddl property, I can create both tables. Sometimes, I want to recreate the Course table without recreating the Student table.

Is it possible to use hbm2ddl to recreate the Course table without recreating the Student table?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hbm2dll property supports only these values - `validate | update | create | create-drop.`. Their description is,

- validate: validate the schema, makes no changes to the database.
- update: update the schema.
- create: creates the schema, destroying previous data.
- create-drop: drop the schema at the end of the session.

So it won't be possible to recreate only a specific table. I think you could look for other ways like [Flyway](http://flywaydb.org/) for database migrations.